# Struggling with beginner math proofs

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Proofs have me feeling entirely stupid.  Its strange to know how to perform calculus level math, but be lost trying to do a math proof on a simple inequality statement.  I'm not necessarily looking for a direct answer, but more of a nudge in the right direction.  My homework is based on completion points (trying will get me a full score), but I'd like to be able to do as much of it on my own as I can, so just a nudge would be great.

```
Problem:

a, b, c and d are real numbers
a ≥ b. 

Prove that if a + c ≤ b + d then c ≤ d.

I have set up the problem:

Givens                                        Goals
1) a, b, c, d are real numbers (premise)      a + c ≤ b + d → c ≤ d
2) a ≥ b                       (premise)
3) a + c ≤ b + d               (premise added 
                               for deduction 
                               method)        c ≤ d
```

Comment: if $x + \epsilon \leq y$, and $\epsilon \geq 0$,  $x \leq y$. If $w \geq z$, $w-z \geq 0$. These are the only pieces you need.

Comment: @joe_04_04 Just for fun, try proving $1+1 = 2$. Its simple and uses similar approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You just have to prove it by contrapositive: keeping the hypothesis $a\ge b$, what can you deduce from $\;\neg (c\le d)$, i.e. from $\;c>d\,$?

Comment: Hmmm, the only thing I can think to do from c > d is to add a to both sides and get a + c > a + d.  Then, since b is smaller than or equal to a, I would assume I could swap the right side a for b, (a + c > b + d)because it wont alter the statement, but I have no clue if this last move is valid, and if it IS a legal move, what to call it.

Comment: You conclusion is correct: you deduce $a+c>b+d$, in other words you deduce $\neg(a+c\le b+d)$. You want to prove $P\implies Q$, and you proved $\neg Q\implies \neg P$, which is equivalent.

Comment: We're the way I worked my givens up a comment above your correct?  Was my statement about substituting a for b (because it doesn't change the statement) correct?

Comment: It's perfectly correct. You have the right to add inequalities. My comment was just to insist on the logical structure of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $x\ge y$ iff $x-y\ge 0$, you can try to rearrange your given inequality to $a-b\le d-c$. Do you see how this gives the conclusion?